# Показать больше/скрыть для записей на angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Есть записи, есть функция "развернуть комментарий":

```
$scope.showText = 'Read Full Review';
$scope.showTextstatus = false;
$scope.readmore = 'ReviewComment';
$scope.readmoreprofile = function() {
    if ($scope.showTextstatus == false) {
        $scope.showTextstatus = true;
        $scope.readmore = 'ReviewCommentread_more';
        $scope.showText = 'Less Read Review';
    } else {
        $scope.showTextstatus = false;
        $scope.readmore = 'ReviewComment';
        $scope.showText = 'Read Full Review';
    }
};

<div class="ProfileReviewData" ng-repeat="review in reviews">
 <p ng-click="readmoreprofile()" class="ReadFullReview orange_text">
     {{showText}}
 </p>
</div>
```

проблема: состояние общее для всех итемов `review`. В одном месте кликаем - открывает/скрывает полный текст всех комментариев. Как сделать так, чтобы у каждого итема было свое состояние(развернуто/свернуто)?

Comment: Покажите, где в шаблоне вы используте переменную **showTextstatus**.

Comment: Нигде. Она переключается только в контроллере. Мопед не мой. Не знаю зачем так сделали.

Comment: Если нигде в шаблоне **html** не используется переменная **showTextstatus**, то и работать открытие\закрытие не будет. Поищите, где-то должно быть написано что-то вроде `ng-show='showTextstatus'` или `ng-if='showTextstatus'`.

Comment: Оно работает, но для всех записей сразу. Через ctrl+F поискал `showTextstatus`, перепроверил, нету такого в хтмл.

Comment: Значит плохо ищите. Или используется `ng-show='showText=="Less Read Review"'` :). Откройте в консоли браузера(F12 - in Chrome) вкладку *Elements*, и посмотрите на ваши блоки, который открываются\закрываются.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko а если не привязываться к этому конкретному коду? как такое сделать? с сохранением требования, что есть массив записей и его в `ng-repeat` выводим?

Comment: В таком случае, обновите Ваш вопрос, с указанием новых требований.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, что бы у каждого элемента было свое состояние открытости\закрытости, надо каждому элементу добавить флаг, который бы указывал на открытое\закрытое состояние.

Пример на [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/1wvnu9qy/).

```js
angular.module('ExampleApp', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', function() {

    this.reviews = [{
      theme: "A",
      isShow: false,
      text: "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"
    }, {
      theme: "B",
      isShow: false,
      text: "BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB"
    }, {
      theme: "C",
      isShow: false,
      text: "CCCCCCCCCCCCCC"
    }, {
      theme: "D",
      isShow: false,
      text: "DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD"
    }];

    this.open = function(review) {
      review.isShow = !review.isShow;
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="ExampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController as vm">
    <div ng-repeat="review in vm.reviews">
      {{review.theme}}
      <button ng-click="vm.open(review)">
        {{review.isShow?"Закрыть":"Открыть"}}
      </button>
      <div ng-show="review.isShow">
        {{review.text}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Пример показа кнопки открыть\закрыть в зависимости от длины текста.

Пример на [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/ew5bqqn9/).

```js
angular.module('ExampleApp', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', function() {

    this.reviews = [{
      theme: "S",
      limit: 10,
      text: "short text"
    }, {
      theme: "A",
      limit: 10,
      text: "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA2"
    }, {
      theme: "B",
      limit: 10,
      text: "BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB2"
    }, {
      theme: "C",
      limit: 5,
      text: "CCCCCCCCCCCCCC2"
    }, {
      theme: "Huge limit",
      limit: 30,
      text: "DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD2"
    }];

    this.isShowButton = function(review) {
      return review.text.length > review.limit;
    }
    this.open = function(review) {
      if (review.limit) {
        review.oldLimit = review.limit;
        review.limit = null;
      } else
        review.limit = review.oldLimit;
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="ExampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController as vm">
    <div ng-repeat="review in vm.reviews">
      Limit: {{review.limit}}
      <button ng-show="vm.isShowButton(review)" ng-click="vm.open(review)">
        {{review.limit?"Открыть":"Закрыть"}}
      </button>
      <div>
        {{review.text|limitTo:review.limit}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, но не понимаю как сделать переключение между коротким и длинным вариантом текста. Например как сделать чтобы работало это https://jsfiddle.net/jth3e5L3/ ?

Comment: А что в представленном фидле не работает?

Comment: Нужна немного другая логика: по-умолчанию доступна часть сообщения(например 140 символов), Если сообщение больше 140 символов - показывается кнопка "Показать больше", которая подгружает остальное сообщение. И именно в том, как реализовать вот эту смену состояний моя проблема.

Comment: Посмотрите изменненный фиддл https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/ew5bqqn9/

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте использовать переменную из скоупа ng-repeat элемента, например, назовите `opened` или `closed`, тогда в контроллере писать ничего не надо будет, обойдетесь только разметкой.

```
<div class="ProfileReviewData" ng-repeat="review in reviews">
 <p ng-click="opened = !opened" class="ReadFullReview orange_text">
     <span ng-show="!opened">Read Full Review</span>
     <span ng-show="opened">Less Read Review</span>
 </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Мне кажется, для спрашивающего Ваш пример будет подобен *магии*. Потому что он не знает о том, что создается изолированный `$scope` внутри `ng-repeat`. Ответ не очень очевиден)